# PLSQL bitmask values

Tags: oracle, bitmask

I am in this situation, I cannot validate the bit for the print permission. Unfortunately I can't have a bitmask with a single bit lit. Can you give me some suggestions?

```
SELECT 
  DECODE(BITAND(00000000100000100000000000000001, 1), 1, '1', '0') AS READ,
  DECODE(BITAND(00000000100000100000000000000001, 131072), 131072, '1', '0') AS COPY,
  DECODE(BITAND(00000000100000100000000000000001, 8388608), 8388608, '1', '0') AS PRINT
  FROM 
DUAL
```

The result is the following

```
R C P
- - -
1 1 0
```

Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: 00000000100000100000000000000001 is a decimal number, 100000100000000000000001 which when converted to binary happens to have bits 1 and 18 set to one, and bit 24 set to zero. So if you want to use `bitand` you need to convert your 'binary' value to a real number, as the first argument expects. So... where is that value coming from, and what data type is it - a zero-padded string? If it is a string, and you're looking for a single bit, it would be simpler to pull that out with `substr()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The BIT_AND function has both arguments as numbers, and there is no bit vector.

For example:

```
select bin_to_num(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1) from dual;

OUTPUT>
8519681
```

```
with 
datum as
(select bin_to_num(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1/*print*/,0,0,0,0,0,1/*copy*/,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1/*read*/) val from dual)
select 
  decode(bitand(val, 1), 1, '1', '0') as read,
  decode(bitand(val, 131072), 131072, '1', '0') as copy,
  decode(bitand(val, 8388608), 8388608, '1', '0') as print
from  datum
```

[image]